# Function meaning, how is it deleting zero expression genes?

Tags: r, expression, sparse-matrix, delete-row

I'm working with an expression matrix obtained by single cell RNA sequencing, but I have a question related with the R code one mate has sent me...

```
sort(unique(1 + slot(as(data_matrix, "dgTMatrix"), "i")))
# there isn't more details in the code...
```

In theory, this function is to delete non expressed genes (if it's zero in all samples, it think...), but it's impossible for me to understand it, anyone can give me a tip?

Comment: your object data_matrix is converted to a dgTMatrix, this object may have different slots but you're interested only in I. for some reason you add 1 to those, and you keep only unique values. Nothing is "deleted". It's hard to help further, consider giving us the output of `dput(head(dgTMatrix,50))`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, thanks for your help! I think I have just understood the code (see answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I have understood this code... let's try to explain it! (please, correct me if I'm wrong).

Our data has a structure of sparse matrix (ie. more handly in regards to memory, [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix)) and with `as` it's coerced to a specific format for this kind of matrix (Triplet Format for Sparse Matrices, [link](https://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node38.html)): three columns with *i* and *j* index for these non-zero values.

```
y <- matrix_counts   # sparse matrix        
                AAACCTGAGAACAACT-1 AAACCTGTCGGAAATA-1 AAACGGGAGAGCTGCA-1 
ENSG00000243485                  1                  .                  .                  
ENSG00000237613                  .                  .                  2

y2 <- as(y, "dgTMatrix")  #triplet format for sparse matrix
  i j x
1  9 1 1  #in row(9) and column(1) we have the value 1
2 50 1 2
3 60 1 1
4 62 1 2
5 78 1 1
6 87 1 1
```

After, it takes only the column "i" (`slot(data, "i")`), because we only need the row index (to know what rows are different to zero), and delete duplicates (`unique`) to finally obtain a vector with the row index which will be used to filter the raw data:

```
y3 <- unique(1 + slot(as(exprs(gbm), "dgTMatrix"), "i"))
[1]  9 50 60 62 78 87
data <- data_raw[y3,]
```

I am a bit confused with `sort` and `1+`, but I think this is the basic concept. So, to summarize, we take the row index from this non-zero rows (genes) and use it to filter our raw data... another original method for delete non-expressed genes, interesting!